# Function to split data while retrieving from database to Order By for VAR CHAR column

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Do MySQL have any function by which I can split data of a column while reading it ?

I have data such as A-A10 , A-A20 , A-A110 stored in a column .

Now I want to sort the result by this column.

How do I use ORDER BY to do this sorting?

Is there any function in MySQL by which first I can split the column data or remove A-A from the data and then sort by the left data i.e. numbers (10,20,110).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there only ever three characters before the number? If so, you can use this:

```
... ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(column, 4) AS SIGNED)
```

Edited in response to **sqlchild**'s comment below.

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks a lot , but sir , it did not work alone , I had to use : ORDER BY CAST( SUBSTRING (column , 4) AS SIGNED )